# What is the solution for the "Invalid constant value" error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error in my Flutter app when trying to run it. The error message is "Invalid constant value." and it is pointing to this specific line (line 4 and 45) of code (obscureText).

The error seems to be related to the use of the const keyword in this line. I am trying to create a to hide and show password text, but the const keyword is causing an issue. Can someone please explain what this error means and how I can resolve it in my code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const RunMyApp());
}

class RunMyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const RunMyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<RunMyApp> createState() => _RunMyAppState();
}

class _RunMyAppState extends State<RunMyApp> {
  bool passwordVisible = false;
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool obscureText = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    passwordVisible = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Show or Hide Password in TextField'),
            ),
            body: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: !obscureText,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(obscureText
                          ? Icons.visibility
                          : Icons.visibility_off),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          obscureText = !obscureText;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Enter password';
                  }

                  return null;
                },
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant create const `InputDecoration` because the `icon` and `onPressed` is depended/changes on run time.

Remove the const before `decoration: InputDecoration(`

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Password',
  prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock_open),
  suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(obscureText
          ? Icons.visibility
          : Icons.visibility_off),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          obscureText = !obscureText;
        });
      }),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const RunMyApp());
}

class RunMyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const RunMyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<RunMyApp> createState() => _RunMyAppState();
}

class _RunMyAppState extends State<RunMyApp> {
  bool passwordVisible = false;
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  bool obscureText = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    passwordVisible = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.green),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Show or Hide Password in TextField'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            controller: passwordController,
            obscureText: !obscureText,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'Password',
              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock_open),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(obscureText ? Icons.visibility : Icons.visibility_off),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    obscureText = !obscureText;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Enter password';
              }

              return null;
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```